# pytest skip on other Inheritance classes

Tags: python, inheritance, automation, pytest

I have an issue with pytest and class Inheritance.
When pytest load an inheritance class that marks as skip, all other brothers also marks as skip.
This happened only during executions when run --collect-only, everything looks good, and only the relevant class return as a skip.

My project class struct is:

```
basePreperationClass(object) 
\
 baseTestsClass(basePreperationClass)
 | \
 |  spesisic_1_PreperationClass(baseTestsClass)
 |   |\
 |   | TestClass1(spesisic_1_PreperationClass)
 |   |\
 |   | @pytest.mark.skip(reasun="Test Class not Implemented")
 |   | TestClass2(spesisic_1_PreperationClass)
 |   |\
 |   | TestClass3(spesisic_1_PreperationClass)
 | \
 |  spesisic_2_PreperationClass(baseTestsClass)
 .
 .
```

When I marked TestClass2 with a skip, all next test classes that use spesisic_1_PreperationClass also skipped

what and why is that happened and is there another way to do it? marking inheritance class as skip without affect other test classes

as a workaround, for now, I just marked `TestClass2.__test__` as False so it will not be collected at all.
The reason to run it while it's not implemented is to get in the report results the real coverages by getting which tests not execute

more details for reproduceing

python 2.7.16 (my code not upgraded yet to 3.9)
pytest version 3.5.1
pytest-sugar-0.9.2

the test file looks like this:

```
import pytest


class BasePreper_1(object):
    __test__ = False


class BaseTests_1(BasePreper_1): # dont run this tests 
    __test__ = False

    def test_1(self):
        pass

    def test_2(self):
        pass


class ExtendPreper_1(BaseTests_1): 
    __test__ = False


class TestClass1(ExtendPreper_1): # dont run this tests 
    __test__ = False

    def test_3(self):
        pass

@pytest.mark.skip(reason="Event class not implemented yet")
class TestClass2(ExtendPreper_1): # skip this tests 
    __test__ = True

    def test_3(self):
        pass

class TestClass3(ExtendPreper_1): # run this tests - this is the issue where inheritanced tests also skiped 
    __test__ = True

    def test_3(self):
        pass


class BaseTests_2(BaseTests_1): # don't run tests - if you like to change __test__ to True  and you will see that its also skpiped while expected to execute 
    __test__ = False


class TestClass4(TestClass2):  # this tests expected to skiped 
    def test_4(self):
        pass
```

the run log looks like this

```
Test session starts (platform: darwin, Python 2.7.16, pytest 3.5.1, pytest-sugar 0.9.2)
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: //tmp/pytest_tests, inifile:
plugins: sugar-0.9.2

 test_preper_1.py::BaseTests_1.test_1 ✓                                                                                                                                                     8% ▉
 test_preper_1.py::BaseTests_1.test_2 ✓                                                                                                                                                    17% █▋
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass2.test_1 s                                                                                                                                                     25% ██▌
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass2.test_2 s                                                                                                                                                     33% ███▍
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass2.test_3 s                                                                                                                                                     42% ████▎
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass3.test_1 s                                                                                                                                                     50% █████
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass3.test_2 s                                                                                                                                                     58% █████▉
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass3.test_3 ✓                                                                                                                                                     67% ██████▋
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass4.test_1 s                                                                                                                                                     75% ███████▌
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass4.test_2 s                                                                                                                                                     83% ████████▍
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass4.test_3 s                                                                                                                                                     92% █████████▎
 test_preper_1.py::TestClass4.test_4 s                                                                                                                                                    100% ██████████

Results (0.03s):
       3 passed
       9 skipped
```

####### When I run with python3.9 and pytest6.2.1 the issue not reproduced #######

```
/tmp/pytest_tests  python3 -m pytest -vvvv                                                                                        340ms  Tue Dec 29 15:18:28 2020
========================================================================================== test session starts ==========================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /tmp/pytest_tests
collected 10 items

test_preper_1.py::TestClass2::test_1 SKIPPED (Event class not implemented yet)                                                                                                                    [ 10%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass2::test_2 SKIPPED (Event class not implemented yet)                                                                                                                    [ 20%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass2::test_3 SKIPPED (Event class not implemented yet)                                                                                                                    [ 30%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass3::test_1 PASSED                                                                                                                                                       [ 40%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass3::test_2 PASSED                                                                                                                                                       [ 50%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass3::test_3 PASSED                                                                                                                                                       [ 60%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass4::test_1 SKIPPED (Event class not implemented yet)                                                                                                                    [ 70%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass4::test_2 SKIPPED (Event class not implemented yet)                                                                                                                    [ 80%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass4::test_3 SKIPPED (Event class not implemented yet)                                                                                                                    [ 90%]
test_preper_1.py::TestClass4::test_4 SKIPPED (Event class not implemented yet)                                                                                                                    [100%]

===================================================================================== 3 passed, 7 skipped in 0.02s ======================================================================================
```

RESOLVED:
looks like a bug in pytest 3.5.1 - when upgrading pytest to 4.6.11 the issue resolved

Comment: This should not happen - I suspect there is something else in your code that causes it. Can you show us a reproducible example?

Comment: issue description update with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrade pytest to 4.6.11 resolved this issue